# What phrasal verb or phrase do you use to refer to this action?

Tags: idiomatic-language, phrase-choice

[image]

He was standing flat on his hands.

I was thinking it makes sense, but the "flat" doesn't make sense. It does make sense to say "stand flat on his head", but I am not sure why that's ok, but I can't say "stand flat on his hands", and is "stand on his hands" even appropriate here? I feel like you can choose a better phrase to describe this.

Comment: While there might be a specialist term in yoga or perhaps some martial arts.  This posture doesn't have a common name in English.  As always with single word requests, please use a bilingual dictionary first.

Comment: I suggest you make a google (or whichever engine you use) image search

Comment: _Stand flat on his head_ doesn't make sense to me. I would say he was balancing on his hands.

Comment: A crouching hand-stand perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned in comments, the position in your image appears to be some kind of yoga position that may have a specific name used by English-speaking yogis, but you'd likely have to know about yoga to know that word and not all English speakers would recognise it.

If I had to describe it, I would probably say he is *balancing on his hands whilst in a crouch position*.

"Standing on his hands" would **not** accurately describe what is happening in this picture. This phrase would lead most people to think of someone in a completely vertical position, like in this image:
[image]

The likely reason we say *standing* on one's hands for this position is because they are in a reverse upright stance. That is not the case with your image. If he rolled backwards 90 degrees he would be flat on his feet but not in a 'standing' position.

"Standing on one's *head*" would mean that their head is touching the floor and supporting their weight, or doing so along with their hands.

Comment: I believe it's [crow pose](https://yogapractice.com/yoga/how-to-do-crow-pose-kakasana-in-yoga/).  But I agree, few English speakers would know or use that term.